# Implicit wait in WebDriver doesn't pause execution

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I initialized and set my driver as below:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin", Vars.FFPATH);
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
desiredCapabilities.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(desiredCapabilities);
driver.navigate().to(siteurl);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, SECONDS);
```

I assume, it should wait for 30 seconds before executing rest of code.
It doesn't work, there is no waiting time, execution takes only 8 seconds.
I tried to use FluentWait to to make some waiting time by waiting for elemnt to be clickable.

```
FluentWait<WebDriver> wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webpage.linput));
```

Error message:

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:787)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.(FluentWait.java:102)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.(WebDriverWait.java:71)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.(WebDriverWait.java:45)

I checked variable `webpage.linput` with `Logger` and it has a valid value, the xpath for the given element, so it is not null.
Variable created here:

```
By linput = By.xpath("//*[@id=\"formA\"]/p[1]/label");
```

Versions:

```
WebDriver 3.5.2
GeckoDriver 0.18.0
Firefox 55.0.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things.

**implicitlyWait**

it shouldn't be

```
driver.navigate().to(siteurl);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, SECONDS);
```

it should be

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, SECONDS);
driver.navigate().to(siteurl);
```

Also, implicit wait doesn't pause the exeuction, it just increase the timeout for every action (i.e. findElement, click)

**pageLoadTiemout:**

Also, if you want to increase the time out for page load implicit wait is not going to help. you should use `pageLoadTiemout`

check the following page. 
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html

For **second problem**

user webdriver wait rather than fluent wait.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webpage.linput));
```

and if you just want to **pause the execution**

use `Thread.sleep()` method.

Comment: I get same exception for `WebdriverWait`.

Comment: could you update the question with code where you create `webpage.linput` element.

Answer (score 1):

A few words about **`Implicit Wait`**:

[**`ImplicitWait`**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) as per the official [**documentation**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) is to configure the **`WebDriver`** instance i.e. the `driver` to poll the **`HTML DOM`** for a certain amount of time (interms of **`NANOSECONDS`**, **`MICROSECONDS`**, **`MILLISECONDS`**, **`SECONDS`**, **`MINUTES`**, **`HOURS`** or **`DAYS`**) when trying to find an element or elements if they are not immediately available. The default setting is **0** which means the `driver` when finds an instruction to find an element or elements, the search starts and results are available on immediate basis.

As per your code you have initialized the **`ImplicitWait`** as:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, SECONDS);
```

But the `End Point` is never called. To know more about **`ImplicitWait`** you can have a look at this [**discussion**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672693/using-implicit-wait-in-selenium/45674706#45674706).

Finally, you have initiated `FluentWait` but the implementation of `FluentWait` is not present in your code. Your code resonates the implementation of `WebDriverWait`. Hence you face **`NullPointerException`**

### Solution:

Without any further lines of code in your code block I feel you don't need any of the waits (**`ImplicitWait`**, **`WebDriverWait`**, **`FluentWait`**). You can proceed without initiating any of them.

### Update:

Incase you need to wait for any particular state of any particular `WebElement`, Selenium have provided the in-built **`ExplicitWait`** i.e. **`WebDriverWait`** where you can choose from 50 odd **`ExpectedConditions`** conditions. See this [**documentation**](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits-reference) and this [**discussion**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759) for more details.

Comment: You said: "You can proceed without initiating any of them." In this case how could I wait during execution? If I execute it without wait, I get error, that element is not found. I used the exact same code with Webdriver 2.53 and it was working earlier.

Comment: @plaidshirt Good Question, Incase you need to wait for any particular state of an particular element Selenium have provided the `ExplicitWait` i.e. `WebDriverWait` where you can choose from 50 odd `ExpectedConditions` conditions. See this [documentation](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits-reference) and this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759) for more details.

Comment: I see, but don't understand why the same code isn't working with different versions.

Comment: @plaidshirt There had been some changes in the core functionality of Selenium when we migrated from Selenium 2.x to Selenium 3.x. Hence we need to take care of the changes. If my Answer have catered to your Question please **`Accept`** the **`Answer`**. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `implicit wait` before URL like this:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, SECONDS);
driver.navigate().to(siteurl);
```

Use `Explicit wait` instead of `fluent wait` like below code:

```
WebDriverWait waitForElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
waitForElement.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webpage.linput));
```