# Selenium Explicit wait

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can any one let me know how and where to implement Explicit Wait in POM frameowrk?

I mean, where should i implement explicit wait code? In POM classes or in Test Case classes?

since now, i have implemented the EW code line in POM class and within the constructor body, below code

```
public RegistrationPage (WebDriver driver)
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(GenderRadioButton));
    }
```

This worked fine for me, but not 100% sure whether or not this is a correct place to implement Explicit wait, need some insight on this plz

--- Ram

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace implicit wait with explicit wait (selenium webdriver & java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java)

Answer (score 1):

You could try with this:

```
public RegistrationPage (WebDriver driver, int timeOutSeconds)
{
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeOutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
            .withTimeout(timeOutSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .pollingEvery(RETRY_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .until(ExpectedConditions
                    .visibilityOf(By.xpath(xpath)))
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeOutSeconds, CLASS_VARIABLE_IMPLICIT_TIMEOUT);
}
```