# Selenium explicit waits with python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I believe this question is unique as this is specifically for Python and not related with the Java issue mentioned in the other thread.

I'm going through [Selenium's documentation regarding explicit waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) but I can't create code to illustrate each explicit waits use cases.

The example below works (ie returns True)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

#match title tag
def title_is(driver, title, timeout=3):
    try:
        w = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
        w.until(EC.title_is(title))
        return True
    except:
        return False

print title_is(driver, 'Google',timeout=3)
```

But the example below doesn't work (I use a different explicit wait condition)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

#try to grab <div id="als">
def presence_of_element(driver, timeout=3):
    try:
        w = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
        w.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(By.ID('als')))
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

I've experimented with multiple forms of syntax but I can't make any explicit wait condition to work excepted the title_is

I would really appreciate your feedback as I'm obviously missing something here.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace implicit wait with explicit wait (selenium webdriver & java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java)

Comment: @DebanjanB OP is not replacing implicit waits... that link doesn't apply.

Comment: Your syntax doesn't match the examples in the link you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import traceback

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

def error_catching():
    traceback.print_stack()
        print '--------------'
        traceback.print_exc()
        return False


#try to grab <div id="gbw">
def presence_of_element(driver, timeout=5):
    try:
        w = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
        w.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'gbw')))
        return True
    except:
        error_catching()
```

Comment: After someone else pointed out the error in your code you answer your own question and accept this answer?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax of `presence_of_element_located` is incorrect. It takes a tuple of a locator's type `By.ID` and value `als`

`w.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'als')))`

See:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits

Comment: I've tried to correct my syntax using the tuple w.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'als'))) however I still get a False return

Comment: In general, when catching a non-specific exception, it's always a good idea to return the stack trace to help with debugging rather than returning `False`.

`False` could mean anything. In this case it was a `NameError` because you didn't include `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By` in your imports.

If you try and run this again with the import, you'll get a `TimeoutException` because 'als' doesn't exist on a page.

If you try and locate the div ID 'cst', it'll return True!

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much James, I'm posting the solution now based on your feedback