# java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException while clicking on Facebook Post Button

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action, webdriverwait

The element is enabled and is displayed. However, I get an error when trying to click on the button element.

> Error: java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Checkout my code for more details.

```java
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element, element.getLocation().x, element.getLocation().y).wait(3000);
element.click();
```

Comment: try this:
synchronized(actions){
actions.moveToElement(element, element.getLocation().x, element.getLocation().y)
                        .wait(3000);
}

Comment: Why are you using `wait()`? this is not one of Selenium waits...

Comment: I have added an answer. Hope it will help you

Answer (score 1):

### IllegalMonitorStateException

As per the *Java Docs* [IllegalMonitorStateException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalMonitorStateException.html) is thrown to indicate that a thread has attempted to wait on an object's monitor or to notify other threads waiting on an object's monitor without owning the specified monitor.

```
public class IllegalMonitorStateException
extends RuntimeException
```

The relevant methods inherited from class [java.lang.Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) are as follows:

- `Object.notify()`: Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor.
- `Object.notifyAll()`: Wakes up all threads that are waiting on this object's monitor.
- `Object.wait()`: Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the `notify()` method or the `notifyAll(`) method for this object.
- `Object.wait(long)`: Causes the current thread to wait until either another thread invokes the `notify()` method or the `notifyAll()` method for this object, or a specified amount of time has elapsed.
- `Object.wait(long, int)`: Causes the current thread to wait until another thread invokes the `notify()` method or the `notifyAll()` method for this object, or some other thread interrupts the current thread, or a certain amount of real time has elapsed.

---

As you are using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) these `wait()` methods can't be used here and you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) in conjunction with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) and you can use the following solution:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("css_of_the_element"))
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element))).click().build().perform();
```

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Difference between driver.manage.wait(long timeout) and Explicit wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48356364/difference-between-driver-manage-waitlong-timeout-and-explicit-wait/48356970#48356970)

Answer (score 0):

You can only wait on an object if you've acquired the lock for it using synchronized.

```
synchronized (driver)
{
    driver.wait();
}
```

**Try this:**

```
 synchronized(actions){
 actions.moveToElement(element, element.getLocation().x, element.getLocation().y).wait(3000);
 }
```