# Selenium : How to solve org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have read a few online articles and they all point to 1 direction and that is when the page is loading the element is not found.  In my setData() you can see I have tried a few things such as use of wait, implicitwait and 1st click and then send the username. However nothing seems to be working. I also thought of using "wait" inside pageProperties but later changed my mind because that would probably be a bad design.

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state
```

System information: Windows 10, ChromeDriver 2.37.544315, chrome=65.0.3

**Code**:

```
public class Tour {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    //browser URL information
    public WebDriver getBrowser(String browser, String url){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");

        if(browser.equals("cc")){
            driver= new ChromeDriver();
        }
        driver.get(url);
        return driver;
    }

    // User name and continue button property from 1st page
    public void pageUserNameProperty(String un){
        WebElement login=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='usernameOrEmail']"));
        WebElement cont_btn=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@type,'submit')]"));

        //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='usernameOrEmail']")));
        login.sendKeys(un);
        cont_btn.click();

    }
    // Password and continue button property from 2nd page
    public void pagePassTourProperty(String psd){
        WebElement password=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']"));
        WebElement lgn_btn=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@type,'submit')]"));

        //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='usernameOrEmail']")));
        password.sendKeys(psd);
        lgn_btn.click();

    }

    // Supply Data for test from excel
    public void setData(){
        Tour tour= new Tour();
        tour.getBrowser("cc", "https://wordpress.com/log-in");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
        WebElement login_field=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='usernameOrEmail']")));
        login_field.click();
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(18, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        tour.pageUserNameProperty("JoeThomas");
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='passTour']")));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        tour.pagePassTourProperty("psd231");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tour tour= new Tour();
        tour.setData();

    }

}
```

Error:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7) on port 2644 
Only local connections are allowed. 
Apr 18, 2018 7:09:26 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession 
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state   (Session info: chrome=65.0.3325.181)   
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:33:15.31Z' System info: host: 'XYZ', ip: '123', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_91' 
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba15..., userDataDir: C:\Users\CHQ-SH~1\AppData\L...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 65.0.3325.181, webStorageEnabled: true} 
Session ID: 3298d88e517d756790ab6792e45257f1    
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Thank You for your time and suggestion.

**Experiment:**

```
public class Tour {

    public static WebDriver driver;

    //browser URL information
    public WebDriver getBrowser(String browser, String url){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\chq-sheikhr\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");

        if(browser.equals("cc")){
            driver= new ChromeDriver();
        }
        driver.get(url);
        return driver;
    }

    // User name and continue button property from 1st page
    public void pageUserNameProperty(String un){
        WebElement login=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='usernameOrEmail']"));
        WebElement cont_btn=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@type,'submit')]"));

        login.sendKeys(un);
        cont_btn.click();

    }
    // Password and continue button property from 2nd page
    public void pagePasswordProperty(String psd){
        WebElement password=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']"));
        WebElement lgn_btn=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@type,'submit')]"));

        password.sendKeys(psd);
        lgn_btn.click();
    }

    // A method - isElementExists to check whether that element exists or not
    public boolean isElementExists(By xpath){
        return driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@id='usernameOrEmail']")).size() > 0;
    }

    /*create a method waitForElement and pass wait time in seconds to it, it is not a hard code wait as it
     *  will continuously check whether that element is exist or not and then it will wait for 1 seconds on 
     *  every iteration of for loop
     */
    public boolean waitForElement(int timeInSeconds, By xpath){
        try{
            for(int i=0;i<timeInSeconds;i++){
                if(isElementExists(xpath))
                    return true;
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void setData(){
        Tour tour= new Tour();
        tour.getBrowser("cc", "https://wordpress.com/log-in");
        tour.waitForElement(10, By.xpath("//input[@id='usernameOrEmail']"));
        tour.pageUserNameProperty("JoeThoman");
        tour.pagePasswordProperty("pasd123");


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tour tour= new Tour();
        tour.setData();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you call `login_field.click()`? It is a text field. You should click on the submit-button.

Comment: It is a text field, I clicked on the field to make sure that the cursor is there first and then I send the username in that field.

Comment: Please add the full stack trace to the question in order to see at which pint the Exception is actually thrown.

Comment: Added above. Thank You.

Comment: Update:After making the change in setData() 1)Click on login text field and then implicitWait makes sometimes pass and sometimes fail.

public void setData(){
  Tour tour= new Tour();
  tour.getBrowser("cc", "https://wordpress.com/log-in");
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
  WebElement login_field=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='usernameOrEmail']")));
  login_field.click();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(18, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  tour.pageUserNameProperty("Joe");

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state
```

...implies that the element with which you are trying to interact is in a state during which actions cannot be performed.

---

### InvalidElementStateException

[InvalidElementStateException](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/InvalidElementStateException.html) is a type of [WebDriverException](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriverException.html) which indicates that a *WebElement* with whom you are trying to interact is in a state in which actions cannot be performed with it. Such instances may arise when an element is being obscured by another element while clicking or the desired element perhaps is not being visible on the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp).

---

### Solution

You have to consider a few facts as follows :

- Never mixup *implicitlyWait()* and *WebDriverWait()* as the [documentation](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) clearly mentions the following :

> Do not mix implicit and explicit waits. Doing so can cause unpredictable wait times. For example setting an implicit wait of 10 seconds and an explicit wait of 15 seconds, could cause a timeout to occur after 20 seconds.

So you need to remove all the instances of *implicitlyWait()*.

- As you need to *send characters* to the **Email Address or Username** field so instead of *ExpectedConditions* method `visibilityOfElementLocated()` you need to use [`elementToBeClickable()`](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#elementToBeClickable-org.openqa.selenium.By-) method.
- A simple script to access the url `https://wordpress.com/log-in` and *send characters* to the **Email Address or Username** field is as follows :

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/path/to/geckodriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();
  driver.get("https://wordpress.com/log-in");
  new WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='usernameOrEmail']"))).sendKeys("JoeThomas");
  ```
- Snapshot of the WebClient :

[image: WebClient]

---

### Update

As per your counter question within your comments the *WebDriverWait* polls the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) at certain intervals (default 500 ms) till the configured amount of time (30 seconds in your case). The element/s is/are returned back as soon as the [ExpectedConditions](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) is met. For example, if the desired element is found within 1 second, it is returned and your next line of code executes. There is no delay involved. As per the [WebDriverWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) constructor you can always configure the  **timeOutInSeconds** and **sleepInMillis** i.e. polling interval.

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [Replace implicit wait with explicit wait (selenium webdriver & java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759)

Comment: I was able to use it. I am curious to know, is putting "driver,30" where you as a developer asking it to wait for that specific time-if this a bad practice or not?

Comment: @SheikhRahman Checkout my answer update and let me know if any further queries.

Answer (score 3):

To make it **consistent** please **follow below steps** :

**A)** **create a method - isElementExists** to check whether that **element exists or not** as follows :

```
public boolean isElementExists(String xpathOfElement){
    return driver.findElements(By.xpath(xpathOfElement)).size() > 0;
}
```

**B)** Now create a method **waitForElement**  and pass **wait time in seconds** to it, **it is not a hard code wait** as it will continuously check whether that **element is exist or not and then it will  wait for 1 seconds** on **every iteration** of for loop as follows :

```
public boolean waitForElement(int timeInSeconds, String xpathOfElement){
    try{
        for(int i=0;i<timeInSeconds;i++){
            if(isElementExists(xpathOfElement))
                return true;
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

**C)** So once it return true **you can perform the action** on that element.

I have **used xpath** for locating element, you can **use whichever** you want.

Comment: @Sheikh Rahman : Could you please try this and let me know if you face any issue ..?

Comment: Pritam I tried this code, I was not able to make it work inside the setData(). I think it is because I was not sure how to use it(my lack of expertise). I will give another try and paste the code so that you can see what I am doing incorrectly. Thank You once again.

Comment: please check the code I added above under Experiment section. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled if your application is dealing with Jquery. This code will wait until your page is fully loaded with all the required data and will avoid **invalidelementstateexception** .

**Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidElementStateException: invalid element state**

```
public static boolean waitForJSandJQueryToLoad() {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getWebDriver(), 30);

    // wait for jQuery to load
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jQueryLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            try {
                System.out.println(
                        "Request = " + ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active"));
                return ((Long) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // no jQuery present
                System.out.println("no jQuery present");
                return true;
            }
        }
    };

    // wait for Java script to load
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jsLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            try {
                System.out.println(
                        "Request = " + ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").toString());
                return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").toString().equals("complete");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // no jQuery present
                System.out.println("no jQuery present");
                return true;
            }
        }
    };

    return wait.until(jQueryLoad) && wait.until(jsLoad);
}
```