# Types of Explicit Wait in Selenium webdriver (Java)?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, explicit

What are the types of waits present in the Explicit Wait in Selenium webdriver (Java)?
Is there any types in Explicit Wait?
if so please elaborate..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace implicit wait with explicit wait (selenium webdriver & java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java)

Comment: There is no classification of Explicit Wait. Explicit wait is one type of wait in Selenium. The types of wait are: Implicit wait, Explicit wait and Fluent wait.

Answer (score 2):

There are following waits:

**FluentWait**

This is special wait where You can set time to wait for a certain condition, as well as the frequency with which to check the condition like eg. wait for 10s and check every 1s, and ignore "NoSuchElementExceptions" exception, if You anticipate that this exception will happen for some time.

```
  Wait wait = new FluentWait(driver)
    .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

  WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function() {
    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
    return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
  }

  });
```

**Explicit wait** 
It is kind of wait where You can set it up to wait for any condition you might like. Usually, you can use some of the prebuilt **ExpectedConditions**

Types of Expected Conditions:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
```

**Implicit wait** 
wait for element, until exception is thrown while initialising object, and its defined through entire session

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.get("http://...");
 WebElement myDynamicElement = driver.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"));
```

**PageLoadTimeout**
How long it will until page is loaded:

```
 driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(100, SECONDS);
```

**SetScriptTimeout**

If you have asynch scripts. Time to wait for an asynchronous script to finish execution before throwing an error.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(100,SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no more types of wait in Explicit Wait as per my knowledge.We have only Implicit Wait, Explicit Wait and Fluent Wait.