# IllegalStateException: Unable to locate element by name for com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.UnexpectedPage with HtmlUnitDriver while getTitle()

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser, htmlunit-driver

Here is my basic code for launching HTMLUnit browser and getting the title. while running the code i am getting the title as null and later it is throwing the following execpetion:

Jars used:

- htmlunit-driver-2.33.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
- selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar

Code trials:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;

public class HtmlUnitDriverTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.get("https://google.com");
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("testing");

    }

}
```

O/p:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate element by name for com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.UnexpectedPage@2e32ccc5
>
> at org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver.findElementByName(HtmlUnitDriver.java:1285)

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider a couple of facts:

- Inducing `Thread.sleep(5000);` just after invoking the `HtmlUnitDriver()` actually makes no sense. You could have used the `Thread.sleep(5000);` after you have invoked `driver.get()`. However as per *best practices* hard-coded `Thread.sleep(n)` and *Implicit Waits* should be replaced by the *WebDriverWait*.
- Here you can find a detailed discussion on [Replace implicit wait with explicit wait (selenium webdriver & java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759)
- You are seeing the *title* as **null** as the driver is trying to extract the *Page Title* even before the *Page Title* is rendered within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp)
- As a solution using **htmlunit-driver-2.33.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *Page Title* to *contain a character sequence* before extracting and you can use the following solution:
- Code Block:

  ```
  import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
  import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

  public class A_HtmlunitDriver_2_33_0 {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

          WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
          driver.get("https://google.com");
          new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains("Go"));
          System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
      }
  }
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Google
  ```