# Unable to locate element using HtmlUnit and WebDriver on Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, webdriver, htmlunit, mockmvc

[Same title question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53044022/illegalstateexception-unable-to-locate-element-by-name-for-com-gargoylesoftware) already exists, however the environment seems to be different.

I'm trying to execute Spring Boot Web MVC test using MockMvc and WebDriver, so I don't need to run Selenium Server.

I created [sample project on GitHub as public repository](https://github.com/ecormaksin/spring-test-html-integration).

I try to impelent the code referencing [Spring Framework Document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-server-htmlunit-webdriver) and [Spring Boot Document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.spring-mvc-tests).

The test code works when using [MockMvc and HtmlUnit](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-server-htmlunit-mah) ([MessageControllerMockMvcAndHtmlUnitTest.java](https://github.com/ecormaksin/spring-test-html-integration/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/testhtmlintegration/presentation/MessageControllerMockMvcAndHtmlUnitTest.java)).
However, when I execute the test using [MockMvc and WebDriver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-server-htmlunit-webdriver) ([MessageControllerMockMvcAndWebDriverTest.java](https://github.com/ecormaksin/spring-test-html-integration/blob/master/src/test/java/com/example/testhtmlintegration/presentation/MessageControllerMockMvcAndWebDriverTest.java)), the error occurs as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to locate element by name for com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.TextPage@~
```

Does anyone know what is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by myself.

I just made 2 mistakes.

1. I misstyped the URL (`messages` not `messagges`)
2. I tried to operate hidden element. So I need to operate by JavaScript.

- before (wrong)

```java
this.id.sendKeys(id);
```

- after (correct)

```java
JavascriptExecutor javascriptExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
javascriptExecutor.executeScript("document.getElementById('id').value = '" + id + "';");
```