# Python Selenium Explicit wait and send keys with xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, implicitwait

I am working on speeding up Selenium web scraping by replacing `implicitly_wait` to `WebDriverWait` with `send_keys` and `click`. I am a little confused on how to achieve that.

This is my code for `inplicitly_wait`:

```
def ncd_web_scraping(df):
    df['new_column'] = 'Not_sure'
    url = 'url'
    for i in df.index:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        driver.get(url)
        name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="person"]')
        name.send_keys(df.loc[i, 'Name'])
        state = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="state"]')
        state.send_keys(df.loc[i, 'State'])
        botton = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/form/button')
        botton.click()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        if soup.find('h5'):
            df.loc[i, 'new_column'] = 'Yes'
        else:
            df.loc[i, 'new_column'] = 'No'


    return df
```

Can anyone help me with how to `webDriveWait` to rewrite the code?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Once the button clicked required HTML.Please post the HTML or share url?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing [implicitwait](/questions/tagged/implicitwait) with [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712431/replace-implicit-wait-with-explicit-wait-selenium-webdriver-java/45715759#45715759) your effective code block will be:

```
def ncd_web_scraping(df):
    df['new_column'] = 'Not_sure'
    url = 'url'
    for i in df.index:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='person']"))).send_keys(df.loc[i, 'Name'])
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="state"]').send_keys(df.loc[i, 'State'])
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/form/button').click()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
        if soup.find('h5'):
            df.loc[i, 'new_column'] = 'Yes'
        else:
            df.loc[i, 'new_column'] = 'No'
    return df
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```